# Hang on vss when getting latest files using ant script

Tags: ant, visual-sourcesafe

I am trying to get latest files from vss using ant script.I wrote ant target as mentioned

```
 <target name="prepare">   
 <vssget localPath="C:\" recursive="true" ssdir="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VSS\win32" login="ss,rr" vsspath="$\\srv01\SVSS\PIS"/> </target>
```

I am running ant build.xml script from command prompt but didn't get any message.Please help me

Comment: Did you try to run target (project) in `verbose` mode (`ant -verbose` or `ant -v`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try (if srcsafe.ini is under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VSS):

```
<vssget localPath="C:\" recursive="true" dbpath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VSS\srcsafe.ini" login="ss,rr" path="$/srv01/SVSS/PIS"/> </target>
```

Check out this page: http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/vssget.html

Comment: I tried to add srcsafe.in.<target name="prepare"> <vssget localPath="C:\" recursive="true" serverpath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VSS\srcsafe.ini" ssdir="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VSS\win32\" login="ss,rr" vsspath="$\\srv01\SVSS\PIS"/> </target>.But i got error "C:\build\build.xml:25: Failed executing: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Stud
io\VSS\win32\ss" Get $\\srv01\SVSS\PIS -GLC:\build -I-  -R   -Yss,************   With a return code of 100"